# Create nested list from multiple lists pair elements

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, nested

I have `n` lists with `n` elements which looks like this, in this example I will show only one with `2` elements, but it could be `n`:

```
['-', '-']
['4.500.740', '924.372']
['1.978.095', '3.802.674']
['3.434.599', '3.614.503']
['8.588.294', '4.973.343']
```

I need to create one single nested list that looks like the next one:

```
[['-','4.500.740','1.978.095','3.434.599','8.588.294'],['-','924.372','3.802.674','3.614.503','4.973.343']]
```

I've been looking with many related questions to this, but I can't figure it out yet, so any advice will be appreciated.

Comment: `zip`is what you are looking for

Comment: `list(zip(*lists))`? But how are these lists related? Is this a 2d list or are they just floating loose? If it's a 2d list, please add `[]` around it and comma-delimit it so there's no ambiguity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use list comprehensions:

```
l1 = [['-', '-'],
      ['4.500.740', '924.372']]

l2 = [[a[n] for a in l1] for n in range(len(l1))]

print(l2)
```

Comment: What about n elements?

Comment: Okay, I'll add that...

Comment: Does that mean if there are 5 lists, each list must contain 5 strings?

Comment: Yup. If lists have 3 elements separated by comma, the nested list should have 3 lists like this  [[],[],[]] with the element equivalent of each one, all the first elements in list one, all the seconds in second, etc.

Comment: Then my answer does just that :)